In Qiskit, is it possible to simulate a Rabi oscillation at the Circuit level through NoiseModel?
With NoiseModel in Qiskit we can add damping terms, for example through thermal_relaxation_error. I'd like to know if there is a way to simulate Rabi oscillation at the circuit level (i.e. plotting the qubit excitation probability as a function of a rotation angle with some decoherence occurring).
For instance, if I implement something like:
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter
from qiskit_aer.noise import (
    NoiseModel,
    thermal_relaxation_error,
)

# --- Noise Model ---
T1 = 100e3 # ns
T2 = 200e3 # ns
time_ry = 200e3
errors_ry = [
    thermal_relaxation_error(T1, T2, time_ry)
]
noise_thermal = NoiseModel(basis_gates=['ry'])
noise_thermal.add_quantum_error(thermal_relaxation_error(T1, T2, time_ry), 'ry', [0])
sim_noisy = AerSimulator(noise_model=noise_thermal)
passmanager = generate_preset_pass_manager(
    optimization_level=0, backend=sim_noisy
)

# --- Circuit ---
circuit = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)
theta = Parameter('theta')
circuit.ry(theta, 0)
circuit.measure(0, 0)

circuit_transpiled = passmanager.run(circuit)
nshots = 4000
# Run and get counts
res = []
for th in np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100):
    passmanager = generate_preset_pass_manager(
        optimization_level=0, backend=sim_noisy
    )
    circuit_transpiled = passmanager.run(circuit.assign_parameters({theta: th}))
    result_noisy = sim_noisy.run(circuit_transpiled, shots = nshots).result()

    counts_noisy = result_noisy.get_counts(0)
    if '1' not in counts_noisy:
        counts_noisy['1'] = 0
    res.append(counts_noisy['1'] / nshots)
plt.plot(res)

I get an oscillation between 0 and some value (the longer the gate time, the smaller the value), but this is not the Rabi evolution I would expect (i.e. the oscillation is not damped and it does not converge to 0.5). I know there are better ways to simulate Rabi oscillation (QuTiP), but doing this in Qiskit at the QuantumCircuit level would be a powerful tool to add some other gates after the time evolution and see what happens.
A QuTiP example that reproduces the behaviour I'd like to achieve with Qiskit is the following:
import numpy as np
from scqubits import Transmon
from qutip import mesolve, ket2dm, Qobj
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tmon = Transmon(EJ = 10, EC = 0.2, ng = 0, ncut = 11)
H = tmon.hamiltonian(energy_esys=True)
H = Qobj(H) * 2 * np.pi
evals, ekets = H.eigenstates()
psi_g, psi_e = ekets[0], ekets[1]  # basis(2, 0)
sx = psi_g * psi_e.dag() + psi_e * psi_g.dag()
sz = psi_g * psi_g.dag() - psi_e * psi_e.dag()

Trabi = 100  # us
decay_rate = 1 / Trabi
c_op_list = []
c_op_list.append(np.sqrt(decay_rate) * ekets[0] * ekets[1].dag())

H0 = 0.5 * (evals[1] - evals[0]) * sz
psi_g = ekets[0]  # basis(2, 0)
psi_e = ekets[1]  # basis(2, 1)
rabi_power = 0.5
Hd = rabi_power * sx
Heff = [H0, [Hd, "sin(wd*t)"]]
args = {"wd": (tmon.E01() * 2 * np.pi)}
psi0 = psi_g
tlist = np.linspace(0.0, Trabi, 201)
result = mesolve(Heff, psi0, tlist, [c_op_list], [ket2dm(psi_e)], args=args)
plt.plot(tlist, result.expect[0])

Is there a way to achieve it?
Thanks

I probably figured this out. Applying many RY gates sequentially does the trick.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel, thermal_relaxation_error

# --- Parameters ---
T1 = 10e3  # ns (relaxation time)
T2 = 20e3
time_step = 50  # ns (discretization step for the rotation)
nshots = 200

# Noise model
noise_model = NoiseModel()
error = thermal_relaxation_error(T1, T2, time_step)
noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error, 'ry')  # Add to idle operations

# Simulator
simulator = AerSimulator(noise_model=noise_model)

# --- Circuit Construction ---
n_steps = 300  # Number of steps to discretize the Rabi oscillation
theta = np.pi / 50
results = []

for step in range(1, n_steps + 1):
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)
    for _ in range(step):
        circuit.ry(theta, 0)

    circuit.measure(0, 0)
    transpiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, simulator)
    result = simulator.run(transpiled_circuit, shots=nshots).result()
    counts = result.get_counts()
    prob_1 = counts.get('1', 0) / nshots
    results.append(prob_1)

# --- Plot Results ---
time = np.linspace(0, n_steps * time_step, n_steps)  # Time axis in ns
plt.plot(time, results, label="Simulated Rabi Oscillations (damped)")
plt.xlabel('Time (ns)')
plt.ylabel('Excitation Probability')
plt.title('Rabi Oscillations with Decoherence')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

